# VirtualBox Machine auto shutting down, how do I stop it from auto shutdown

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, virtualization

I downloaded and installed these [virtual machines](https://github.com/xdissent/ievms) for IE8/IE9 web development, IE9 stays running but it appears the IE8 VM is constantly shutting itself down, and it is saving the state (it doesn't boot fresh) so I think it is Vbox. How can I debug what is causing this specific VM to shutdown. It is stable when I use it and only happens when I am not watching it, it never happens when I am using the VM.

Comment: These test VMs are typically unlicensed copies of Windows and the anti-piracy measures in Windows will reboot your machine every few hours.  Could this be what is happening?

Comment: The machine can be set to hibernate after some idle time?

Comment: These are not unlicensed copies, they are legitimate versions that just never get registered and are legal. The machine isn't rebooting, since the state is being saved. I will check into hibernation.

Answer (score 29):

heavyd is right.

https://github.com/xdissent/ievms/issues/22

In the Windows guest, open the command prompt and enter

```
slmgr /rearm
```

(not --rearm as cited in that post, since this is Windows).  You can do that up to twice apparently, to extend by 30 days each time.  Apparently the [iectrl](http://xdissent.github.io/iectrl/) tool from ievms also works but I didn't try that.

Comment: When I enter the code I get, "Error: 0xC004F025 Access denied: the requested action requires elevated priilages. "  Please help!

Comment: @Alex Try right clicking on the Command Prompt icon and selecting "Run as Administrator"

Answer (score 6):

The `slmgr /rearm` command needs to be run as Administrator. Otherwise you'll get the error:

> "Error: 0xC004F025 Access denied: the requested action requires elevated privileges."

For Windows 8:

1. Get to Desktop
2. Right-click bottom left Start icon to display the menu
3. Select "Command Prompt (Admin)"
4. Click "OK" on the dialog box.
5. In the Command Prompt run `slmgr /rearm`

For other windows versions, [visit this TechNet page](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc947813(v=ws.10).aspx).

Comment: Looks like this is not for Windows 10? After success message and reboot I still see `Windows License is expired` on the desktop bottom-right.

Answer (score 3):

### Explanation:

This is caused by the **WLMS (Windows License Monitoring Service)**.

Some suggested to try: `slmgr /rearm`, which will only temporary fix this issue,
but you will need to run this every 30 days or so, and it didn't seem to work on my machine. (Windows 10 x64 Virtualbox)

Permanent solution (and the only thing that worked in my case) is to **delete WLMS** Service completely.

### Permanent solution:

1. Download "[pstools](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/pstools)"
2. Extract it anywhere (e.g. "`C:\pstools`")
3. Run `cmd.exe` as "Admin", or `powershell -Verb runAs`
4. Navigate to that directory (e.g. "`cd 'C:\pstools'`")
5. Type "`PsExec.exe -i -d -s cmd`" (a new GUI window will pop up)
6. Click "Agree" on the license agreement dialog box
7. Then you will get another command prompt running under “**nt
   authoriy\system**” (You can check it by running the command "`whoami`" )
8. Type "`sc delete WLMS`"
9. Type "`regedit`" (This will open another Window: "**Registry editor**")
10. Navigate to: "`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/System/CurrentControlSet/Services`" and find "WLMS"
11. Right-click the Key and press "Delete"
12. Restart Your computer

Comment: Brilliant, thanks! When using Powershell I needed `powershell -Verb runAs` to run it as Admin. Plus the command apparently needed to be case sensitive with extension: `./PsExec.exe -i -d -s cmd`.

Comment: @AlexanderRutz  Yes, if you are using PowerShell, you'll need that...I've changed it, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This is because the Windows expired.

if `slmgr /rearm` does not work, and warn "the maximum allowed number of re-arms has been exceeded ..."

[This tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b5kJJmrQwbk) quickly solved the issue for me.

Then, do this again `slmgr /rearm`

Restart the VM.