# Modern.ie Windows keep shutting down in VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine

I run VirtualBox and and a VM from [www.modern.ie](http://www.modern.ie) (Win 7). It runs fine but after tabbing away from it for a while it seems to shut down. Is there some automatic shutting down option in VirtualBox and/or Win 7 from modern.ie what I'm unaware of?

It's really annoying having to restart the VM 7 times per day.

Comment: It's Microsoft's way of punishing you for trying to develop websites that support their defunct curse of a browser. One last smear of salt in the wound.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The virtual machine shuts down because it is not a fully licensed version. 30 days after running the VM for the first time, they will expire, and subsequently shut down after an hour.

You have to reinstall the VM.

To prevent that, create a snapshot of the machine after setting it up, and rewind to that snapshot once the evaluation period expires.

Comment: @Ramhound It is a license thing -- I think it's mentioned somewhere in the release notes or EULA of the virtual machines. I don't know if you could change the license on the VM afterwards, but that'd require you to buy one anyway.

Comment: Alright.  It just sounded like the VM was just suspendeding.  I also don't know if the license can be changed those virtual machines serve a specific function in my eyes

Comment: I agree that if people are just using them to test software then it seems pointless and annoying to make them keep shutting down.  It just makes windows/IE testing even more of a b*llache.

Comment: I don't understand the point either... and it happened to me after 2 days of installation, so wth!

Comment: same here, fresh installation, 89 days before expiration but the vm shuts down after 1 hour

Answer (score 1):

You can try open the command prompt and type:

```
slmgr /rearm
```

Ref: [VirtualBox Machine auto shutting down, how do I stop it from auto shutdown](https://superuser.com/questions/479376/virtualbox-machine-auto-shutting-down-how-do-i-stop-it-from-auto-shutdown)

Comment: Must use "Run as administrator" on the command prompt.

Answer (score 0):

Change the VM power saving options. By default it will sleep after 20 minutes if no movement is detected. Change it to `Never`.

More detailed steps:
http://www.pcworld.com/article/256309/tweeking_windows_7s_sleeping_habits.html